Relationship between Semigroups and Markov Chains?
I am taking a class on Markov Chains for the purpose of applying them to engineering failure of machines.
Our prof was talking about the "Semigroup" property of Markov Chains and I found it difficult to understand. Here is my attempt to unpack this.
Definition of Semigroups: I read online that a Semigroup in general can be understood as follows:
$$f: S \times S \rightarrow S$$

the Operation $f$ is a Semigroup
$\times$ represents the Associative Property, i.e.  $(a \cdot b) \cdot c = a \cdot (b \cdot c)$
$S$ is a set

So the idea being that if we have some set, and we can apply an Operation on this Set such that the output of the Operation obeys the Associative Property and the output is still in the original set (i.e. Closure), then this Operation is a Semigroup.
As an example, if we take all real numbers, the operation of addition is a Semigroup because the addition obeys the Associative Property and the result of adding any amount of real numbers will still be a real number.
Discrete Markov Chain: Given a transition matrix, we define a Discrete Markov Chain as:
$$
P_{ij} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} & \cdots & p_{1m} \\
p_{21} & p_{22} & \cdots & p_{2m} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
p_{m1} & p_{m2} & \cdots & p_{mm}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^{m} p_{ij} = 1$$
$$P(X_t = i | X_{t-1} = j, X_{t-2} = k, \ldots) = P(X_t = i | X_{t-1} = j)$$
Given that the DTMC is in state j at time t-1 and in state k at time t-2, the probability of the DTMC being in state i at time = t is equal to the probability of the DTMC transitioning between state j and state i in 1 unit of time.
Continuous Time Markov Chain: Given a Generator Matrix $Q$ and a time dependent transition matrix $P(t)$, we can define a Continuous Time Markov Chain as:
$$
Q_{ij} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
q_{11} & q_{12} & \cdots & q_{1m} \\
q_{21} & q_{22} & \cdots & q_{2m} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
q_{m1} & q_{m2} & \cdots & q_{mm}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$q_{ii} = -\sum_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \neq i}}^{m} q_{ij}$$
$$\frac{dP(t)}{dt} = QP(t)$$
$$P(X(t + s) = k | X(t) = j, X(u), 0 \leq u < t) = P(X(s) = k | X(0) = j)$$
Given that the CTMC was in state j at time=t and in some sequence states during time = u and time = 0 ... the probability of moving to state k in s units of time equals to the probability of being in state k at time = s given that the CTMC was in state j at time=0.
We also note the two following points (Exponential Distribution of state i's holding times and the instantaneous probability of moving from state i to state j ):
$$f_T(t) = \lambda_i e^{-\lambda_i t}$$
$$P_{ij} = \frac{q_{ij}}{\sum_{j} q_{ij}}$$
Semigroup Property in the context of Markov Chains: This is where I get confused. I learned about the two following equations:

Chapman-Kolmogorov Equation for Discrete Time Markov Chains:

This gives us a method to calculate the transition matrix at some point in the future given the initial transition matrix. The Chapman Kolmogorov equation can be written as:
$$P^{(s+t)} = P^s P^t$$
For example, if we are modelling the two flip outcomes "stochastic coin" with the following transition matrix:
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
p_{hh} & p_{ht} \\
p_{th} & p_{tt}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I could use the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation to answer the following question. If $P$ is my transition matrix at time=0 and I am currently in heads - what is the probability of me still being in heads after s time units?
$$
\prod_{i=0}^{s} P^i = P \cdot P \cdot \cdot P \cdot ...P = P^s = \begin{bmatrix}
p^s_{hh} & p^s_{ht} \\
p^s_{th} & p^s_{tt}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus, the answer is $p^s_{hh}$

Kolmogorov Forward Equation for Continuous Time Markov Chains:

$$\frac{dP(t)}{dt} = QP(t)$$
$$P(t) = e^{tQ}$$
$$\exp(Qt) = I + Qt + \frac{1}{2!} Q^2t^2 + \frac{1}{3!} Q^3t^3 + \ldots$$
Using the same coin example from above (i.e. change the problem to find the probability of going from heads at time=0 to heads at time = t+s), we define:
$$
Q = \begin{bmatrix}
-q_{hh} & q_{ht} \\
q_{th} & -q_{tt}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Applying the Kolmogorov Forward equation, we get (i.e. the HH element to the numerically exponentiated matrix $\exp(Qt)$):
$$P(X_{t+s} = H | X_0 = H) = \sum_{x \in S} P(X_{t+s} = H | X_t = x) P(X_t = x | X_0 = H)$$
$$P(X_{t+s} = H | X_0 = H) = \sum_{x \in S} [e^{Q(t+s)}]_{Hx} [e^{Qt}]_{xH}$$
$$P(X_{t+s} = H | X_0 = H) = [e^{Q(t+s)}]_{HH}$$
Thus, the corresponding HH element in this matrix corresponds to the probability of transition from H to H in time = t+s units.
My Question: I am trying to tie everything together and understand what exactly is the relevance of Semigroups in Markov Chains. Here is my guess:
In DTMCs and CTMCs, the operation $P(s+t) = P(s)P(t)$ is a Semigroup because:

The Associative Property is satisfied, i.e. $P(s+t) = P(s)P(t) = P(t)P(s)$
The Operation $P(s+t)$ is "Closed", i.e. $P(s)P(t)$ is still a valid transition matrix

Thus since both properties have been satisfied, we conclude that this property of transition matrices within Markov Chains are a Semigroup.
Is my understanding of this correct?
Thanks!
